# In mac, not able to view or open a file which displayed while by `locate` command

Tags: mac-osx, filesystems, file-permissions

OS: MacOS

When I try `locate acronym` a folder named acronym and all the contents in the folder are getting displayed, but I am not able to view or open any of those files.

I was able to view and access these a couple of seconds ago.
I did not change the permission.
All I did was remove the `.git` folder from the parent directory.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. We do not normally accept general operating system questions. You may be able to get help on one of our sister sites such as [unix.se], [su] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate` uses a database generated by walking the filesystem.

The database is updated by a low priority background task so can be out of date.

Comment: Oh damn, then are my files gone for good :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyways :)

Comment: it has been more than 24 hours still locate gives me the results

Comment: Only after I shutdown my computer the cache got refreshed :(
For 5 days the cache had the data.